# Distributed database implementation in sql server

Tags: sql-server, distributed-databases

Currently, We have central Database at Head Office and users from sub offices ,scattered around the country, connect to central database. Now we want to distribute the database in disconnected mode at each Sub office level and we want data to be synchronized at the day end at the central Database from all others Databases. We also want transfer of data to all Databases from central Database. Please refer me the tutorial or way to implement this scenario in SQL Server. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty much a textbook example for Merge Replication.  Here is the [Product documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151790(v=sql.105).aspx) describing the scenario, and how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

if you need use sql server for distributed plan, I know about 2 scenario:

1. you can use [Big Data Clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/big-data-cluster/big-data-cluster-overview?view=sql-server-ver15) for store big data in HDFS managed by SQL Server, read about in reference this scenario :
2. Use [Service Broker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-service-broker?view=sql-server-ver15) for Asynchronies 2 or more SQL Server in distribute plans. you can read about in below link:

> Developers can easily create sophisticated applications that use the Database Engine components to communicate between disparate databases, and build distributed and reliable applications.

In other scenario you can use **Always ON**, **Replication** , **Mirror** . but i guess you need use **Service Broker**.